# Altair bar chart assign specific colors based on dataframe column

Tags: jupyter-notebook, altair

I am making a Gantt chart in Jupyter notebook using Altair, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029002/is-there-a-way-to-create-gantt-charts-in-python).

How can I assign specific bar colors to each task? Thanks for any help.

Pandas, altair, and vega are installed. Using Windows 10, Python 3.7.6, Conda 4.6.14.

```
mytaskbars = pd.DataFrame([
    {"task": "Task1a", "start": '2020-06-01', "end": '2020-09-30', "color": 'royalblue'},
    {"task": "Task1b", "start": '2020-06-01', "end": '2021-03-31', "color": 'deepskyblue'},
    {"task": "Task1c", "start": '2020-09-30', "end": '2021-03-31', "color": 'dodgerblue'},
    {"task": "Task2", "start": '2020-06-01', "end": '2021-03-31', "color": 'red'},
    {"task": "Task3", "start": '2020-06-01', "end": '2021-08-02', "color": 'orange'},
    {"task": "Task4", "start": '2020-10-01', "end": '2021-03-31', "color": 'green'},
])

mytaskbars["start"] = pd.to_datetime(mytaskbars["start"])
mytaskbars["end"] = pd.to_datetime(mytaskbars["end"])


chart = alt.Chart(mytaskbars).mark_bar(opacity=0.7).encode(
    x=alt.X('start', axis=alt.Axis(title='Date', labelAngle=-45, format = ("%b %Y"))),
    x2 = 'end',
    y=alt.Y('task', axis=alt.Axis(title=None)),
    color = 'color'
)

chart
```

[image]

Comment: See https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#raw-color-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```py
    color=alt.Color('color:N', scale = None)
```

does the trick

[image]

Comment: Thanks! what does the `:N` mean? I see versions of it in the documentation (`:O`, `:Q`, etc.) but I somehow missed what it means.

Comment: Good question! The `:N` is shorthand for the encoding data type, in this case Nominal. In general it's good practice to include them. For more information see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html#encoding-data-types